# Find the number of non-decreasing and non-increasing subsequences in an array

Tags: algorithm

I am attempting to complete a programming challenge from Quora on HackerRank: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/quora-haqathon/challenges/upvotes

I have designed a solution that works with some test cases, however, for many the algorithm that I am using is incorrect.

Rather than seeking a solution, I am simply asking for an explanation to how the subsequence is created and then I will implement a solution myself.

For example, with the input:

6 6

5 5 4 1 8 7

the correct output is -5, but I fail to see how -5 is the answer.  The subsequence would be [5 5 4 1 8 7] and I cannot for the life of me find a means to get -5 as the output.

> Problem Statement
>
> At Quora, we have aggregate graphs that track the number of upvotes we get each day.
>
> As we looked at patterns across windows of certain sizes, we thought about ways to track trends such as non-decreasing and non-increasing subranges as efficiently as possible.
>
> For this problem, you are given N days of upvote count data, and a fixed window size K. For each window of K days, from left to right, find the number of non-decreasing subranges within the window minus the number of non-increasing subranges within the window.
>
> A window of days is defined as contiguous range of days. Thus, there are exactly N−K+1 windows where this metric needs to be computed. A non-decreasing subrange is defined as a contiguous range of indices [a,b], `a<b`, where each element is at least as large as the previous element. A non-increasing subrange is similarly defined, except each element is at least as large as the next. There are up to K(K−1)/2 of these respective subranges within a window, so the metric is bounded by [−K(K−1)/2,K(K−1)/2].
>
> Constraints
>
> 1≤N≤100,000 days
> 1≤K≤N days
>
> Input Format
>
> Line 1: Two integers, N and K
> Line 2: N positive integers of upvote counts, each integer less than or equal to 10^9
>
> Output Format
>
> Line 1..: N−K+1 integers, one integer for each window's result on each line
>
> Sample Input
>
> 5 3
>
> 1 2 3 1 1
>
> Sample Output
>
> 3
>
> 0
>
> -2
>
> Explanation
>
> For the first window of [1, 2, 3], there are 3 non-decreasing subranges and 0 non-increasing, so the answer is 3. For the second window of [2, 3, 1], there is 1 non-decreasing subrange and 1 non-increasing, so the answer is 0. For the third window of [3, 1, 1], there is 1 non-decreasing subrange and 3 non-increasing, so the answer is -2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given a window size of 6, and the sequence

```
5 5 4 1 8 7
```

the non-decreasing subsequences are

```
5 5
1 8
```

and the non-increasing subsequences are

```
5 5
5 4
4 1
8 7
5 5 4
5 4 1
5 5 4 1
```

So that's `+2` for the non-decreasing subsequences and `-7` for the non-increasing subsequences, giving `-5` as the final answer.

Comment: I wasn't taking into account the different combination of subsequence lengths, the answer is clear now.

Comment: accidentally I clicked on down vote and not able to undo it.Some error.

Comment: @whokares Yup, you can only change your mind in the first 5 minutes. Don't worry about it :)

Comment: @user3386109 haha ! That was unintentional.Thanks for the explanation.